how to get textarea value in Python that doesn't have value field
I'm trying to parse html page and get the value from a textarea, but i can't achieve it, i will put my code (i started with selenium but it didn't work either). I don't really understand where this value is in the DOM 
so the value is in the inspector but not in the html code... I can't find a way to get it. Please can someone explain me ? Thanks !
#coding: utf8
import lxml.html as lh
import urllib.request 

nb = 36893488147419103232
#x=0


#GRAB
#while x<=1: #A changer en fonction du nb de pages à crawl
url_base="https://bitcoin.oni.su/"+str(nb)#+x)
req = urllib.request.Request(url_base, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
doc=lh.parse(urllib.request.urlopen(req))
get_btc_adr = doc.xpath('//textarea[@id="BTCaddrC"]')
print(get_btc_adr, get_btc_adr[0].value)#Tried Value, text, element_Text()....
#x+=1


HTML code is just a description of the initial state of the DOM tree. Usually (even tho html code may contain intial values) values of widget are dynamically inserted; either because the use typed something in, or because a script execution filled in something (for example a value taken from the server). Point is, getting fields content by getting html and parsing it won't work.

So how could i do ? And why can the inspector see it ? Isn't there a way to access this "Value" we can see in the inspector ?

That is a way too broad question. It depends a lot on the context. You haven't describe anything about the situation. What is this website? Is it yours? If not, does it need an account to access data? Does it provide an API? (it certainly has one for itself: the one that let the client get those data from the server. But is it public, and could you make requests to that API? Or is it simple enough to reverse engineer it).

Selenium (maybe ask another question why it didn't work) or an alternative like playwright.

That may sometimes be near impossible. If the website is someone else websites, and they want to prevent any access of the data, except through their website, with their rules... I say "near impossible" rather than "impossible", because it is almost always possible to mimick a browser (that is what selenium is, since you've mentioned it), and make it perform the exact step you would use "by hand" to get those info with the website, and grab the values.

Theoretically, it is never totally impossible to do. But banks, for example, tends to make it hard (by having you type a password on a dynamic keyboard that is never the same ; or, for my bank, using one-time password generated by a ad-hoc device). Or simply by having you click on bicycles or pedestrian crossing. So it may be a very hard task to automate grabbing of data from a website that doesn't want you to do so.

Well even not automating it, if i visit the website (IT IS NOT MINE) i don't see how to get the value, except by making a "copy" from right mouse click...

first you could print doc in your code or print driver.page_html when you use selenium to see what you really get from server. If page uses JavaScript then requests is useless because it can't get values added by JavaScript. Sometimes page may chage IDs and code may not find correct place. And sometimes pages uses hidden widgets to keep data in different place and they use CSS to display then in correct place.

BTW: sometimes it is simpler to check if page load data from server using some API and use this API to get data directly (usually as JSON) without working with HTML.

I found the same value in href in <a id="ExploreBTCAddrC" href="..."> - so maybe this is method to get it.

After looking around and not giving up, i finally made it, here's the working code in case someone encounters same situation :
#coding: utf8
from selenium import webdriver

nb = 36893488147419103232
x=0
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

#GRAB
while x<=1: #A changer en fonction du nb de pages à crawl
    url_base="https://bitcoin.oni.su/"+str(nb+x)
    driver.get(url_base)
    btc_adr = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('BTCaddrC').value")
    with open("result.txt","a") as f:
        f.write(str(nb+x)+" "+btc_adr+"\n")
    print(str(nb+x),btc_adr)
    x+=1

Thanks for all trying to help !

items = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//textarea') for x in items: print(x.get_attribute("value"))

I need only a specific ID's textarea

I used id in code in my answer.

Probably this page uses JavaScript to fill textarea - so it needs Selenium to get it.
And Selenium needs .get_attribute("value") to get value from textarea.

My version:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
#import undetected_chromedriver as uc

# ---

import selenium
print('Selenium:', selenium.__version__)

# ---

#driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=Service(GeckoDriverManager().install()))
#driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path='/home/furas/bin/chromedriver', service_args=['--quiet'])
#driver = uc.Chrome()

# ---

nb = 36893488147419103232
url = f"https://bitcoin.oni.su/{nb}"

driver.get(url)

item  = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//textarea[@id="BTCaddrC"]')
value = item.get_attribute("value")
print(value)

item  = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'BTCaddrC')
value = item.get_attribute("value")
print(value)

Result:
Selenium: 4.15.2
1LgpDjsqkxF9cTkz3UYSbdTJuvbZ45PKvx
1LgpDjsqkxF9cTkz3UYSbdTJuvbZ45PKvx

